# How to get light sensor value

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors

I have following code uses light sensor but not able to display value of event.value[0]...it displays toast only with message "On SensorChanged"
also text is not set to tv where i goes wrong..

here is code

```
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
    {
    if( event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT)
    {
        tv.setText("value: " + event.values[0] + " lux" );   
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"On SensorChanged"+ event.values[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("Sensor Changed", "onSensor Change :" + brightness);
    }

}
```

Comment: on which device are you testing it?

Comment: also you can have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913055/android-changing-brightness-using-sensor/12913246#12913246

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that is contains light sensors to that why it is returning nothing,your code seems fine otherwise,

http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung-phones-9.php

Follow this link to check the model you are testing on and see in features and then sensors

Comment: ...the tech-specs screenshot is of "Galaxy S3 mini" not "Galaxy S".

Comment: sry i got the wrong image that time :) ,,check the link that i have given , That will tell you if the device that you are testing on support Light sensor or not,Thnks

Comment: ..and the "proximity" sensor indicates that the "light" sensor h/w is in fact present on the device. Need to verify if the default Samsung Android/Touchwiz framework (sensor-HAL) exports the light sensor to APPs. CyanogenMod on Samsung I9000 Galaxy S **does** provide the apps with the light sensor data using the underlying hardware. Use `getSensorList(TYPE_LIGHT)` to check this.

Answer (score 3):

Have you registered the listener. There are three parts for using the sensors

1. Create SensorManager and Sensors

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

   private SensorManager mSensorManager = null;
   private Sensor mLightSensor = null;
   ...
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
   mLightSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
   }
   ```
2. Register the sensor you are listening to

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mLightSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
   }
   ```
3. Implement the SensorEventListener methods from part 1.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

   if( sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT)
   {
       Log.d("SensorTest", ""+ sensorEvent.values[0]);
   }
   }

   @Override
   public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Galaxy S **does** in fact have light-sensor hardware.
The proximity sensing is done by the light sensor device. More on this **[here](http://thecodeartist.blogspot.com/2011/01/proximity-sensor-on-android-gingerbread.html)**.

To ensure that you are activating and using the light sensor properly,
verify that **[`getSensorList(TYPE_LIGHT)`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-identify)** returns a valid light sensor.

Thereafter proceed as shown in this **[link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-monitor)**.

Answer (score 0):

Now i get sensor value. But the problem is how to assign that to System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS.
i use following code but not able to assign it. It only works when automatic is enable in brightness setting.

following is the code

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
{
    if( event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT)
    {
        float currentLux = event.values[0];
        brightness=(int)event.values[0];
        brightbar.setProgress(brightness);
        tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv2.setText("value:"+ currentLux+ " lux" );   
        System.putFloat(cResolver, System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE,currentLux);
        android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutpars = window.getAttributes();
        layoutpars.screenBrightness = currentLux;  
        window.setAttributes(layoutpars); 
        Log.d("Sensor Changed", "onSensor Change :" + currentLux);
    }

}
```

Comment: not yet...right now i am working on different project..Actually when i run that code..after that the phone is not getting start..so after that i not tried any more